# What's the difference between Firestore Rules and Firestorage Rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have files I want to make sure to keep secure, once the admin uploads a file into the storage, only he and the user he is sharing the file with has access to the links to download that file. Hence under firestore rules I added the following:

```html
match /users/{userID} {
    allow read: if isOwner(userID) || isAdmin();
    allow write: if isOwner(userID) || isAdmin();
  }
    
    /// FUNCTIONS BELLOW ///
    
    function isAdmin() {
     return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.IsAdmin;
    }
```

However when I tried to add the same rules under Firestorage, the access is constantly denied.

```html
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if isAdmin();
    allow write: if isAdmin();
    }
    
     /// FUNCTIONS BELLOW ///
    
    function isAdmin() {
     return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.IsAdmin;
    }
  }
}
```

Does the Firestorage get method work differently then the Firestore get method?
Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are no `Firestorage Rules`, there are actually rules for **Cloud Firestore** which is the new database from Google, **Firebase Storage** which is used to store images, audio, video, or other user-generated content and **Fireabse realtime database** which is also a NoSQL database.

- [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)

> Security rules provide access control and data validation in a simple yet expressive format.

- [Storage Security
  Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start)

> Storage Security Rules are used to determine who has read and write access to files stored in Cloud Storage, as well as how files are structured and what metadata they contain.

- [Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

> Firebase Realtime Database Rules determine who has read and write access to your database, how your data is structured, and what indexes exist. These rules live on the Firebase servers and are enforced automatically at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are talking about [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/) and [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview)

The issue with your Cloud Storage rules is that you cannot access the Firestore database. If you need to carry over data to assist with authorising a write you could look at [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) Which you could access with `auth.token.admin === true` in your security rules for example that looks at the users auth token for an admin property

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if isAdmin();
      allow write: if isAdmin();
    }

    /// FUNCTIONS BELLOW ///

    function isAdmin() {
      return auth.token.admin === true
    }
  }
}
```